# Change comboBox value based on textBox value? c#

Tags: c#, sql, hyperlink, bind

I'm making PC configuration program, and i'm stuck. On first form I have selection of CPU and information displayed in textBoxes, but on second form I have selection of MoBo's. One of CPU information is socket, which is the first comboBox on Motherboard form. Is there a way that value from textBox can be linked with that comboBox? I used Sql Studio as well.

I really need help, I'm very bad at programming, and I'm only doing this not to fail the semester. Pls help me.

[This is picture of my code for that comboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLAw8.png)

private void MaticnaPloca_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct(soket) from MaticnaPloca", con);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("soket", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);
        cbSoket.ValueMember = "soket";
        cbSoket.DataSource = dt;
        cbSoket.SelectedIndex = -1;
        con.Close();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct(proizvodjac) from MaticnaPloca order by Proizvodjac", con);
        SqlDataReader reader1;
        reader1 = sc1.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("proizvodjac", typeof(string));
        dt1.Load(reader1);
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "proizvodjac";
        comboBox2.DataSource = dt1;
        comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        comboBox2.Enabled = false;
        con.Close();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT (model) from MaticnaPloca order by model", con);
        SqlDataReader reader2;
        reader2 = sc2.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("model", typeof(string));
        dt2.Load(reader2);
        comboBox3.ValueMember = "model";
        comboBox3.DataSource = dt2;
        comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
        comboBox3.Enabled = false;
        con.Close();
        
    }       
            
    private void cbSoket_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        
        try
        {

            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();           
            if (cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1151")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct (proizvodjac) from MaticnaPloca where Soket = '1151'", con);

            else if (cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "AM4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct (proizvodjac) from MaticnaPloca where Soket = 'AM4'", con);

            else if (cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "TR4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct (proizvodjac) from MaticnaPloca where Soket = 'TR4'", con);

            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("proizvodjac", typeof(string));
            dt.Load(reader);
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "proizvodjac";
            comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox2.Enabled = true;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
                          

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
     

        try
        {

            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand();
            con.Open();

            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Asus" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1151")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct (model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'Asus' AND Soket = '1151'", con);
            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Asus" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "AM4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'Asus' AND Soket = 'AM4'", con);
            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Asus" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "TR4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'Asus' AND Soket = 'TR4'", con);


            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Biostar" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "AM4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'Biostar' AND Soket = 'AM4' ", con);
            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Biostar" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1151")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'Biostar' AND Soket = '1151'", con);


            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Gigabyte" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1151")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'Gigabyte' AND Soket = '1151'", con);
            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Gigabyte" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "AM4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'Gigabyte' AND Soket = 'AM4'", con);
            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Gigabyte" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "TR4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'Gigabyte' AND Soket = 'TR4'", con);


            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "MSI" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "AM4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'MSI' AND Soket = 'AM4'", con);
            if (comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() == "MSI" && cbSoket.SelectedValue.ToString() == "TR4")
                sc = new SqlCommand("select distinct(model) from MaticnaPloca where Proizvodjac = 'MSI' AND Soket = 'TR4'", con);


            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("model", typeof(string));
            dt2.Load(reader);
            comboBox3.ValueMember = "model";
            comboBox3.DataSource = dt2;
            comboBox3.Enabled = true;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```

Comment: We really can't guess what you are trying to do. You need to tell us what UI framework you are using (Windows Forms, WPF, something web-y, something else) and you need to show us the code you have as a [mcve]. The answer to your question (*Is there a way that value from textBox can be linked with that comboBox?*) is "Yes". You might also want to spell out "mother board" once for folks who aren't familiar with *MoBo*

Comment: I'm using WPF, I added the picture of my code just now, do I need to add pictures of forms? Sorry I'm not very good at all of this, i will edit that part.

Comment: When you add code to a question, you need to add it as text.  Once you paste it in, if it doesn't show up as code, then press the `{}` button to format it as code.  Note that, until you pasted in your picture of your code, the only hint that you were using a database is that you said *I used Sql Studio* (which I'm assuming is SQL Server Management Studio).  Assuming you are trying to use binding, look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview.  You may want a `BindingList<T>`

Comment: Follow that link I put in my last comment, and look for **Master-detail binding scenario** in the document

Answer (score 0):

Also I don't quite understand what you want to do but I try.

to add textbox text to combobox

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

to get comboBox value, and showing in TextBox

```
int pos = 0; //item position starting from 0 1 2 3 . . . 
textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Items[pos].ToString();
```

Comment: My point is, I need textBox value to influence on combBox selection. My textBox is only informational, for example my textBox says :AM4, and my comboBox needs to preview choice of manufacturers of motherboard based on value AM4. Do you understand me now?